# DIV container not showing in front of Anchor image

Tags: html, css, hover

so i have a situation where i want text to appear over an image using visibility:hidden/visible and also playing with opacity. i cannot do it for some reason. Note that this is in a list because i have other images displayed in the same list but here i am only showing one. below is the html:

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <a class="pic" href="#">
    <img alt="" src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00PU00000096kH2MAI" style="width: 300px; height: 160px;" />
   </a>
   <div class="hovertext"> my hover text</div> 
 </li>
</ul>
```

and the css is here:

```
#gallery ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}

#gallery li{
display:block;
float:left;
width:310px;
height:170px;
margin:0 15px 15px 0;
}

#gallery li a{
display:block;
float:left;
width:300px;
height:160px;
margin:0;
padding:4px;

}


#gallery li a:hover {
color:#FFFFFF;
    opacity:0.6; 
background-color:#666666;
}

#gallery li a:hover .hovertext{
visibility:visible;
  }

.hovertext{ width:300px; height:85px; 
background-color:#666666;
opacity:0;
visibility:hidden;
display:block;
text-align:justify; 
color:#000000; font-size:20px; 
}
```

all this does is allow me to see that the image is opaque and i can see that the div is in the background but i just cannot bring it forward to display in front of the opaque text. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as a side note, the shared `html` doesn't have an element with `id` `gallery` hence the css selectors won't work. please share proper html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following code.

```
 #gallery li a:hover .hovertext{
 visibility:visible;
 }
```

The above code will look the child element of `hovertext` when you hover the link. In your case, it is siblings element. So update your CSS like below.

```
 #gallery li a:hover + .hovertext{
 visibility:visible;
 }
```

Also you have added `opacity:0` for hovertext class. I think there is no need for that one. Because already you have `visibility:hidden` for the same class. So update your CSS like below.

```
 .hovertext{ width:300px; height:85px; 
  background-color:#666666;
  visibility:hidden;
  display:block;
  text-align:justify; 
  color:#000000; font-size:20px; 
  }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kVScL/)

Comment: hi and thanks for the answer. however i still cannot see the div. is it possible that the container in which the list is put could be affecting the display? Would a display: or position: setting on the parent container affect this?

Comment: thanks that did the trick. just had to remove the opacity:0 for it to work. any idea how i can place that text in front of the image instead of beneath it?

Comment: it seems that i cannot edit my previous comment. i figured out the text positioning with z-index and position. thanks again for your help.